# Scala Slick codegen custom naming

Tags: scala, slick, slick-codegen

I'm using slick codegen to generate table definitions for myMySql db. How can I override slick's codegen naming conventions? It generates following code for table query objects:

```
lazy val User = new TableQuery(tag => new User(tag))
```

I want it to look like this instead:

```
lazy val slickUser = new TableQuery(tag => new User(tag))
```

P.S. I have seen this example: https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-customization-example, but I wonder if there is an easier way to achieve this ?

Comment: You will need to override `tableName` of `slick.codegen.AbstractGenerator`.

Comment: Hello. I'm new to this technology, so I would appreciate getting more practical advice. Can it only be done the way as in this example - https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-customization-example, or are there more straight-forward and simple ways, like overriding it in the config, of in the build.sbt "gen-tables" taks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "easier" way. At least I'm not aware of one. But you may find this sbt plugin useful: [sbt-slick-codegen](https://github.com/tototoshi/sbt-slick-codegen). Your `slickCodegenCodeGenerator` in `build.sbt` would look like this then (untested):

```
slickCodegenCodeGenerator := { (model:  m.Model) =>
  new SourceCodeGenerator(model) {
    override def tableName = (dbName: String) => "slick" + dbName.capitalize
  }
}
```